# the service of Geocode isn't present on a real device, how can I fix it?

Tags: android, service, geocoding

I have some problems with the `geocoder`.

I found many posts about this, but most solves the problem testing the apk on a real device.
I have a problem with the lack of service of the `geocoder` right on a real device. How can I fix?

I get the **`latitude`** and **`longitude`**, but I need to get the **address from latitude and longitude** from any type of device. There are alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a network web service from your app, like a query to [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 1):

The geocoder is part of the Google API add-on that isn't part of the AOSP"

So any device that doesn't come with Market, GMail etc will also be missing the Geocoder back-end